# Android App Signing In Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have an android app that I tried adding Google Play Services to. I did some search and from what I understood, I was supposed to follow these steps: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init
I followed all the steps and then when I ran my game to see what would happen, it automatically crashes. Is there anything else I'm supposed to do?

Comment: What are the error logs when it crashes

Comment: That's the weird part about this, I don't get any errors in the log